# How did Rakshas gain supernatural powers?

Tags: rakshasa

There are many stories of Rakshas having supernatural powers. How did Rakshas gain supernatural powers ? Most Rakshas had supernatural powers , they would fly in sky etc.  How did they gain such powers ?

Comment: Rakshasas live on another loka that can't be seen to normal human eyes. I think they are just created with magical powers.

Comment: by doing tapasya (penance)